# FPGA clock multiplication?

Tags: frequency, fpga, clock

I have a basys3 board with a 100MHZ oscillator, I was wondering if it would be feasible to get a 200Mhz clock by pulsing the output on the rising and falling edge of the 100Mhz oscillator. I cant seem to find any material online about people attempting this. thanks for any and all help.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend against it, you should use a [PLL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase-locked_loop) or [MMCM](https://www.xilinx.com/products/intellectual-property/mmcm_module.html) IP modules, which you can [configure](https://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/sw_manuals/xilinx2019_2/ug896-vivado-ip.pdf) in Vivado.